# link is not opening in uiwebview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, urlrequest

I have link as below,

https://payood.test/loofpay/XUYZGlobal/WebForms/checkoutservice%20.aspx?paymentchannel=ddd&isysid=37268474138868&amount=25&description=Transaction From XXX&description2=dsdsd&tunnel=&original=ZXz4kfH9fiVIZ1jWBaGjww3hgwX84CGAahlCcsKWXvs%3d&responseUrl=http://localhost:55766/dsss/Response.aspx&hash=BE0481E5F9AA1C9F5B26A8E93A6ACAAD5888EDE9

When I try to open, its crashing saying below error.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Below is the code I am using

```
link = above link....
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: link)!))
```

Note:

If I use simple link as `http://www.google.com`, it works.

Comment: your problem is `!` this mark you need to make it optional so it won't crash

Comment: @wings : still crashing... with google.com, its fine dear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that url is already encoded but API have issues that they are sending spaces in url.

So I replace spaces with %20

```
link = link.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
```

This way all is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The link you've posted isn't a valid URL. It includes spaces in your description. You didn't encode this correctly.

Comment: this is what I received from the web api... I tried to various `addingPercentEncoding` but still have same issue...

Comment: `link = link.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")` I add this line manually and now its working... I had no other option then this...

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the problem is the link you provide to `URL initializer` is not a valid `url` and because of the `!`, your code can not initial a URL from the string in the following code and it will crash:

```
URL(string: link)!
```

So you have to change the string to some valid url **before** initializing a URL from it. Like this:

```
guard let escapedURLString = link.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) else {
    fatalError("Unknown URL string:\(link)")
}

guard let finalURL = URL(string: escapedURLString) else {
    fatalError("Can not create a url from:\(escapedURLString)")
}

print(finalURL) //to check if it works
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: finalURL))
```